# Symfony 2 multiple bundles, one template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I will have this structure:

```
  -TaskBundle
    -FrontendConroler
    -BackendController
  -Userbundle
    -FrontendConroler
    -BackendController
  -HoursUserBundle
    -FrontendConroller
    -BackendController
```

This is right logic?
Second and main question, I will have 2 base templates, for Frontend and Backend, where I will push base template (one most logic place -BasetemplatesBundle?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is right structure. You can create CoreBundle, and store templates in it, or you can just create in `app / Resources / views /` `frontend.html.twig`, and `backend.html.twig`. Or with orther name.

You can call template:

```
{% extends '::frontend.html.twig' %}
{% extends '::backend.html.twig' %}
```

[**Creating and Using Templates**](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html)